# bash: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar No file or folder of this type (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, installation, composer-php

I tried to install composer globally on my computer (ubuntu 16.04) 
i follow the offcial composer documentation

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

next i use this command ;

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

and when i write "composer" in the terminal i have this error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar No file or folder of this type
```

anyone have an idea of my problem?

Comment: What does `ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | grep composer` output?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 adjol smileusers 1861877 févr. 13 14:29 composer (composer is in red)

Comment: So the command to be used is `composer`. Are you sure that you call it in another way? Have you added any bash alias that contains `composer.phar`?

Comment: i haven't use alias, but i tried yesterday and i have the same message.

Comment: We should know what the script `composer-setup.php` is doing for understanding what's happening here.

Comment: this file is to test if the installer is corrupt or not

Comment: What happens if you delete `/usr/local/bin/composer` and run `composer` again? What’s the result of `which composer`? What’s the result of `dpkg --get-selections | grep composer`?

Comment: i found the problem, i uninstall composer and reset the bashrc and reinstall and finally it works ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to move composer.phar

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
```